# FinancialData returns undefined Units for Volume or randomly fails

Tags: curated-data, units

Recently `FinancialData["IBM","Volume"]` started failing and when it does randomly work, it returns `Quantity[3073167,Shares]` but the units "Shares" fails the test: `KnownUnitQ["Shares"]` returns False.  Previously this request returned a number, not a quantity.  The same effect happens with `FinancialData["IBM","OHLCV"]`, yet `FinancialData["IBM","OHLC"]` (no volume) works just fine.  This is a new recent behavior.  I'm using Mathematica 11.3.0.0

Answer (score 2):

This does appear to be a bug

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

vol = FinancialData["IBM", "Volume"]

(* Quantity[3073167, "Shares"] *)
```

As you pointed out,

```
KnownUnitQ["Shares"]

(* False *)
```

As a result, [`QuantityUnit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityUnit.html) fails

```
vol // QuantityUnit

(* QuantityUnit[Quantity[3073167, "Shares"]] *)
```

As does [`QuantityMagnitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html)

```
vol // QuantityMagnitude

(* QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[3073167, "Shares"]] *)
```

The workaround is to use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
vol[[1]]

(* 3073167 *)

vol[[-1]]

(* "Shares" *)
```

Or without defining a variable,

```
FinancialData["IBM", "Volume"][[1]]

(* 3073167 *)
```

[`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) has the same issue

```
WolframAlpha["trade volume for IBM", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]

(* Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification Shares.

Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification Shares.

Quantity[3.073*10^6, "Shares"] *)
```

Comment: Sent this information to Wolfram support team and they said it does indeed look like a new bug.  Support forwarded the issue to the development team, but no ETA on a fix.